# Read mmapped data memory efficient

Tags: c, mmap

I want to `mmap` a big file into memory and parse it sequentially. As I understand if bytes have been lazily read into memory once, they stay there. Is there a way to periodically tell the system to release the previously read contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This understanding is only a very superficial view.
To understand what really happens you have to take into account the difference of the virtual memory of your process and the actual real memory of the machine. Mapping a huge file means reserving space in your virtual address-space. It's probably platform-dependent if anything is already read at this point.
When you actually access the data the OS has to fill an actual page of memory. When you access other parts these parts have to be brought into memory. It's completely up to the OS when it will re-use the memory. Normally this happens when some data is accessed by you or an other process and no free memory is available. But could happen at any time. If you access it again later it might be still in memory or will brought back by the OS. No way for your process to tell the difference.

In short: **You don't need to care about that. The OS manages all that in the background.**

One point might be that if you map a really huge file this takes up space in your virtual address-space which is limited. So if you deal with many huge mappings and or huge allocations you might want to only map parts of the file at a given time.

**ADDITION:** after thinking a bit about it, I came up with a reason why it might be smarter to do it blockwise-sequential. Although I doubt you will be able to measure that.
Any reasonable OS will look for a block to unload when in need in something like the following order:

1. unmapped files ( not needed anymore)
2. LRU unmodified mapped file (can be retrieved from disc)
3. LRU modified mapped file (same as 2. but needs to be updated on disc before unload)
4. LRU allocated memory (needs to be written to swap)

So unmapping blocks known to be never used again as you go, you give the OS a hint that these should be freed earlier. This will give data that has been used less recently but might be accessed in the future a bigger chance to stay in memory.

Comment: `In short you: you don't need to care about that. The OS manages in the backgound.` That's even better. Thanks!